# C# httpclient hangs at the last request

Tags: c#, request, httpclient, freeze

I have a program which send a couple of thousands of post requests to the server. Everything is working fine until the end of the transmission. After all but one request are sent the program hangs.

Always there is only one request left to make. I am using HttpClient and everything is done async.
Here I create the httpclient:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
                        (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 45;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

var CurrentCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Repo.Username, Repo.Password);

var Handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Credentials = CurrentCredentials,
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic,
    UseProxy = false,
};

var Client = new HttpClient(Handler);

Client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2500);
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-alive");

WebServ = new WebService(Client, ref Repo);
```

Here is where I send the requests:

```
private async Task<string> SendData(string Url, HttpContent[] content, string[] name)
{
    using (var FormData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < content.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (name[i] == "file")
                FormData.Add(content[i], name[i], name[i] + i.ToString() + ".jpg");
            else
                FormData.Add(content[i], name[i]);
        }

        try
        {
            using (var Response = await Client
                                    .PostAsync(Url, FormData)
                                    .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false))
            {
                await App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                           (Action)delegate
                           {
                               Repo.CurrentItem++;
                           });

                using (var StreamResume = new StreamWriter("resume.bkp"))
                {
                    await StreamResume.WriteLineAsync(Repo.CurrentItem.ToString());
                }

                if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                              (Action)delegate
                              {
                                  Repo.Log.Add(Url + " OK" + Repo.CurrentItem);
                              });
                }
                else
                {
                    await App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                              (Action)delegate
                              {
                                  Repo.Log.Add(Url + " Error " 
                                              + Response.Content.ToString());
                              });
                }

                if (Repo.CurrentItem == Repo.NumberOfItems)
                {
                    await App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                             (Action)delegate
                              {
                                  Repo.Log.Add("Data has been imported");
                                  Repo.CurrentState = "Finished!";

                                  Repo.CurrentItem = 0;
                                  Repo.Uploading = false;
                                  Repo.NotUploading = true;
                                  Repo.Resumable = false;

                                  File.Delete("resume.bkp");
                              });
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                 (Action)delegate
                 {
                     Repo.Log.Add("The url is not valid");
                     Repo.CurrentItem = 0;
                 });

            Client.CancelPendingRequests();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I encounter no errors whatsoever only that some threads never exit and the program never terminates. If I have a smaller data set, where only about 180 requests are made, the program does the job never hanging. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: No one know why this is happening?

Comment: Considering 180 requests are fine, can you try this:
a) find out the minimum number of requests that fails consiotently (e.g. all the time).
b) Once you get the number in (a) run the app through burp/fiddler to ensure that the response is actually sent in a timely fashion to 100% of your requests.

Comment: Ok. Will try and come back with the answer